# Selecting text nodes with text not equal to a value

Tags: python, xml

So I have a document that looks roughly like this

```
<detection-run>
<wireless-network>
    <SSID>
        <encryption>WPA+PSK</encryption>
        <encryption>WPA+TKIP</encryption>
        <encryption>WPA+AES-CCM</encryption>
    </SSID>
</wireless-network>
<wireless-network>
    <SSID>
        <encryption>WEP</encryption>
    </SSID>
</wireless-network>
<wireless-network>
    <SSID>
        <encryption>WPA+PSK</encryption>
        <encryption>WPA+TKIP</encryption>
    </SSID>
</wireless-network>
<wireless-network>
    <SSID>
        <encryption>None</encryption>
    </SSID>
</wireless-network>
</detection-run>
```

From this I would want a list containing one encryption node from each SSID. So an element with text "WPA+PSK", another with "WEP", another with "WPA+PSK", another with "None". It does not matter on the WPA ones if it is WPA+PSK or something else, just so long as one encryption node is grabbed.

There are a lot more nodes and there are multiple wireless networks, but the encryption used is all I care about. I am using `lxml` in Python and I need to get one encryption node from each SSID. How would I do this using xpath()?

I have tried a lot of different things and none seem to be working. lxml keeps saying I have an invalid predicate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `//encryption[text()!="WPA-PSK"]/text()` xpath:

```
from lxml import etree

data = """
<detection-run>
    <wireless-network>
        <SSID>
            <encryption>WEP</encryption>
        </SSID>
    </wireless-network>
    <wireless-network>
        <SSID>
            <encryption>WPA-PSK</encryption>
        </SSID>
    </wireless-network>
    <wireless-network>
        <SSID>
            <encryption>WPA2-PSK</encryption>
        </SSID>
    </wireless-network>
</detection-run>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(data)
print root.xpath('//encryption[text()!="WPA-PSK"]/text()')
```

prints:

```
['WEP', 'WPA2-PSK']
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I also was trying to use findall() rather than xpath() which I think caused some problems

Comment: I also am noticing that some of the SSID nodes in the XML have multiple encryption nodes. I really am trying to get a count of the number which use WPA vs WEP vs nothing. If the network uses WPA then it might have multiple encryption nodes whereas for other types it only has one. How could I grab just one encryption node from each SSID and check its text for the type of encryption?

Comment: @thaweatherman could you please edit the question and show the sample input with multiple encryption nodes and the desired output? Would help to help you faster :)

Comment: @thaweatherman if you want just one `Encryption` node for the network, try `//SSID/encryption[1]/text()`. Works for you?

Comment: There are 5856 networks total in my example XML and that predicate gives a length of 6212. That is an improvement though

Comment: @thaweatherman hm, could there be more that one `SSID` per network in the xml?

Comment: Ah ha! I just realized why. This XML file is disgusting, btw. Some wireless networks have a wireless-client child and those also have a SSID element with encryption nodes. I guess those need to be ignored too. I just tried `//wireless-network/SSID/encryption[1]/text()` and that gave me 4579 which is also the same amount of SSIDs associated with a wireless-network. It looks like some of the wireless-network elements don't have an SSID associated. That should solve my problem. Thanks so much for your help!!